# Calculate the probabilities of different outcomes (combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

I am interested in such a problem of combinatorics / theory of chances.

Given:
There are 16 cells. 3 types of symbol - no symbol (NO), symbol1 (SYM1), symbol2 (SYM2).
Number of symbols:
NO - 9
SYM1 - 4
SYM2 - 3
In each cell, randomly one of the symbols appears. The person does not know which cell has which symbol. A person randomly selects 3 cells.

Question:
What is the probability to guess, for example, 2 SYM1 and 1 SYM2?

What I have done:

I know how to solve this problem if there were two types of symbol - no symbol (12) and SYM1 (4).

The probabilities to guess the SYM1 for such a case are calculated by the formula:

```
W (Guessed) = Combin (4; Guessed) * Combin (16-4; 3-Guessed) / Combin (16; 3) * 100
```

where Guessed is the number of guessed SYM1 (0, 1, 2, or 3 guessed symbols)

I understand that there are a total of 10 different outcomes in the case of three types of symbols (brackets indicate how many symbols are guessed):

```
outcome 1: NO (3), SYM1 (0), SYM2 (0)
outcome 2: NO (2), SYM1 (1), SYM2 (0)
outcome 3: NO (2), SYM1 (0), SYM2 (1)
outcome 4: NO (1), SYM1 (0), SYM2 (2)
outcome 5: NO (1), SYM1 (1), SYM2 (1)
outcome 6: NO (1), SYM1 (2), SYM2 (0)
outcome 7: NO (0), SYM1 (0), SYM2 (3)
outcome 8: NO (0), SYM1 (1), SYM2 (2)
outcome 9: NO (0), SYM1 (2), SYM2 (1)
outcome 10: NO (0), SYM1 (3), SYM2 (0)
```

But how do I calculate the probabilities of each outcome?
Thank you in advance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability on what you call  "2 SYM1 and 1 SYM2" equals:$$\frac{\binom{9}{0}\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{16}{3}}$$

More generally we have probability:$$\frac{\binom{9}{x}\binom{4}{y}\binom{3}{z}}{\binom{16}{x+y+z}}$$where $x,y,z$ correspond with the number of appearances of NO,  SYM1 and SYM2, respectively.

This for nonnegative integers $x,y,z$ that satisfy $0\leq x+y+z\leq16$ and under the convention that $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $k\notin\{0,\dots,n\}$.